# Creating good indexes for table

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, mariadb, database-indexes

I'm working with a MariaDB (MySQL) table which contains information about some map points (latitude and longitude) and a quantity.

I'm making a lot of querys that retrieve some of this points and I want to optimize the query **using indexes**. I don't know how to do it well.

My queries are like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.lat, p.lon, p.quantity 
FROM Points p 
WHERE ((p.lat BETWEEN -10.0 AND 50.5) AND 
       (p.lon BETWEEN -30.1 AND 20.2) AND 
       (100 <= p.quantity AND 2000 >= p.quantity)) 
ORDER BY p.name DESC;
```

So, the columns involved in the queries are: `lat`, `lon` and `quantity`.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at [ST_WITHIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/st-within/) and [SPATIAL INDEX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/spatial-index/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is a *spatial index*. You will need to alter the schema of your table (by turning `lat` and `lon` into a single `POINT` or `GEOMETRY` value) to support this, and use specific functions to query that value. Once you've done this, you can create a spatial index using `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX`; this index will allow you to perform a variety of highly optimized queries against the value.

There's more information on using spatial types in MySQL [in the "Spatial Data Types" section of the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html).

Comment: Thanks! But I think I would have to make a lot of changes in a huge project :(

Comment: Unfortunately, that's going to be hard to avoid if you need to optimize spatial queries against this table.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will create a new point column and a trigger that adds the spatial  information into the column when a row is created

Comment: Once done the migration... is possible to index both columns (coordinates and quantity) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple range conditions, even if you have an standard B-tree index on all the columns, you can only get an index to optimize the first range condition.

```
WHERE ((p.lat BETWEEN -10.0 AND 50.5)              -- index on `lat` helps
   AND (p.lon BETWEEN -30.1 AND 20.2)              -- no help from index
   AND (100 <= p.quantity AND 2000 >= p.quantity)) -- no help from index
```

You can either index `lat` or you can index `lon` or you can index `quantity` but your query will only be able to use an B-tree index to optimize one of these conditions.

This is why the answer from @achraflakhdhar is wrong, and it's why the answer from @duskwuff suggested using a spatial index.

A spatial index is different from a B-tree index. A spatial index is designed to help exactly this sort of case, where you need range conditions in two dimensions.

Sorry this sounds like it will cause some rework for your project, but if you want it to be optimized, that's what you will have to do.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will create a new point column and a trigger that adds the spatial  information into the column when a row is created

Comment: I have found that `INDEX(lat, lon)` is better than `INDEX(lat)` because of ICP.

Answer (score 1):

Toss indexes you have, and add these:

```
INDEX(lat, lon),
INDEX(lon, lat),
INDEX(quantity)
```

Some discussion is provided [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)